# Extract multiple pieces to data from a record using grep

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Write a section of a bash script to extract the Description, VolumeId, SnapshotId and StartTime from each record listed below. The intent is sort the records by the StartTime to allow another step to delete records based on this time. I will need these fields to identify validity of certain snapshots. How do you recommend I go about extracting the data from each record so I can sort by the StartTime? In the end I will need to count records and delete the oldest record based on the time and delete the record by extracting the SnapshotId.

Example Data:

```
"Snapshots": [
    {
        "Description": "HipChat_30min_Snapshot",
        "Encrypted": false,
        "VolumeId": "vol-0acc184304bb512a5",
        "State": "pending",
        "VolumeSize": 100,
        "Progress": "4%",
        "StartTime": "2017-02-20T14:02:45.000Z",
        "SnapshotId": "snap-0f9a3613023a3038d",
        "OwnerId": "346720985731"
    },
    {
        "Description": "HipChat_30min_Snapshot",
        "Encrypted": false,
        "VolumeId": "vol-0acc184304bb512a5",
        "State": "completed",
        "VolumeSize": 100,
        "Progress": "100%",
        "StartTime": "2017-02-20T13:53:11.000Z",
        "SnapshotId": "snap-0da7b040554eb0d65",
        "OwnerId": "346720985731"
    }
```

Comment: If this is proper `JSON` suggest using a proper JSON parser like `jq`

Comment: Out of each record I need to extract the StartTime and the SnapshotId and then count the number of records, sort by the time and then select the oldest snapshots.